# SELECTING SUM based on conditional if from another table

Tags: mysql

Database: `mysql` > `ver 5.0`

```
table 1: type_id (int), type
table 2: name_id, name, is_same_as = table2.name_id or NULL
table 3: id, table2.name_id, table1.type_id, value (float)
```

I want to sum values, and count values in `table 3` where `table2.name_id` are same and also include the values of `id` where `is_same_is=name_id`. I want to select all data in `table3` for all values in `table2`.

Apologize if my question is not very clear, and if it has already been answered but I am unable to find a relevant answer. Or dont exactly know what to look for.

```
[data]. table1
id | type
=========
1  | test1
2  | test2

[data].table2
name_id  |  name  | is_same_as
==============================
1        |  tb_1  | NULL
2        |  tb_2  | 1
3        |  tb_3  | NULL
4        |  tb_4  | 1

[data].table3
id    |   name_id  |  type_id | value
======================================
1     |   1        |  1       | 1.5
2     |   2        |  1       | 0.5
3     |   2        |  2       | 1.0


output:
name_id| type_id|SUM(value)
=======================================================
1      | 1      |2.0  < because in table2, is_same_as = 1
2      | 2      |1.0
```

Comment: What have you tried? Also, the question is really not that clear. Provide a test data set with at least 2 rows in each table and show which output you'd like to get.

Comment: [data]. table1
id | type
=========
1  | test1
2  | test2

[data].table2
name_id  |  name  | is_same_as
==============================
1        |  tb_1  | NULL
2        |  tb_2  | 1
3        |  tb_3  | NULL
4        |  tb_4  | 1

[data].table3
id    |   name_id  |  type_id | value
======================================
1     |   1        |  1       | 1.5
2     |   2        |  1       | 0.5
3     |   2        |  2       | 1.0


output:
name_id| type_id|SUM(value)
=======================================================
1      | 1      |2.0  < because in table2, is_same_as = 1
2      | 2      |1.0

Comment: Please add that to the question, it's unreadable in a comment.

Comment: How come that in your result name_id=2 has type_id=2, while in table3 name_id=2 has type_id=1 ?

Comment: Alex Monthy: in table3, name_id has to type_ids assigned with various values

Answer (score 0):

I think the following does what you want:

```
select coalesce(t2.is_same_as, t2.name_id) as name_id, t3.type_id, sum(value)
from table_3 t3 join
     table_2 t2
     on t3.name_id = t2.name_id
group by coalesce(t2.is_same_as, t2.name_id), t3.type_id
order by 1, 2
```

It joins the table on `name_id`.  However, it then uses the `is_same_as` column, if present, or the `name_id` if not, for summarizing the data.

Comment: how do i get only the records if sum(value)/count(value)>=3

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:  (I haven't tested it in MySQL, so there may be a typo)

```
with combined_names_tab (name_id, name_id_ref) as
(
select name_id, name_id from table2
union select t2a.name_id, t2b.name_id
  from table2 t2a 
  join table2 t2b 
    on (t2a.name_id = t2b.is_same_as)
)
select cnt.name_id, t3.type_id, sum(t3.value) sum_val
  from combined_names_tab cnt
  join table3 t3
    on ( cnt.name_id_ref = t3.name_id )
 group by cnt.name_id, t3.type_id
having sum(t3.value) / count(t3.value) >= 3
```

Here's what the query does:

First, it creates 'combined_names_tab' which is a join of all the table2 rows that you want to GROUP BY using the "is_same_as" column to make that determination.  I make sure to include the "parent" row by doing a UNION.

Second, once you have those rows above, it's a simply join to table3 with a GROUP BY and a SUM.

Note: table1 was unnecessary (I believe).

Let me know if this works!

john...

Comment: Depending on the behavior you want, Gordon's answer may be better.  His answer will remove any "name_id = 2" records from showing up with their own result set rows, and simply combine their values into "name_id = 1".  My query will combine "name_id = 2" values into "name_id = 1", but also show you "name_id = 2" values independently.  My guess is that you probably want Gordon's answer.

Comment: Yes this works! I am testing the query on the data set i have obtained.

Comment: Concerning this filter: sum(value)/count(value)>=3, add it to a HAVING clause at the end of the query.  See my edit above.